# print value inside the loop for 1 crore times... without memory timeout in php

Tags: php

I want to print my name inside loop for 1 crore time but it throwing fatal error that Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 10
Even after i set max_execution_time=0

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$startTime = time();
$pos = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <10000; $i++)
{
for ($j = 0; $j <1000; $j++)
{
    $person[$pos] = new Person('dipti');
    echo $person[$pos]->getName() . " | ";;
    $pos++;
}
}
echo "<br>";
$endTime = time();
echo $endTime - $startTime . " seconds taken";

class Person
{
private $name;

/**
 * Person constructor.
 * @param $name
 */
public function __construct($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

}
?>
```

Comment: You ran out of memory. If 4096 bytes is needed for page for your object, then your loop dictates that you need 40960000000 bytes of memory. You ran out.

Comment: But i am set max_execution_time to 0 but it will throw same error.How to assign that size in my file.

Comment: Not time, memory

Comment: i am also set memory limit to 256M ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); but same error

Comment: What would you expect to happen when allocating more than max. memory?